# Create an Array and get Element, or part of String, in One Line - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, delimiter, strstr

To create an array from a string and get an element you need to do this:

```
$string = "1/2";

$array = explode("/", $string);
$elem = $array[0];
```

A little trick lets you use the strstr() and provides the same result as both lines above.

```
$elem = strstr($string, "/", true);
```

The issue is..

1. What if you want to return after the "/" instead of before it, but without the "/" prepended
2. If the "/" does not exist in the array, false is returned

strstr() is not the answer. Is there another method or syntax to get the string before the "/" in one line either by doing an array operation or some string operation?

Comment: What is the obsession people have with one-liners? Is your computer running low on newline characters?

Comment: I haven't downvoted you, I rarely do. I don't know why they do that, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this in php 5.4 +

```
$string = "1/2";

$first = explode("/", $string)[0];
```

[Eval.in example](https://eval.in/210033)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr()`:

```
$after = substr($string, strpos($string, '/')+1);
```

the `+1` makes it skip past the `/`.